# How do I add the same functions back into my code after detaching in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to recreate my `.click functions`, for loops, if statements after they are used the first time. I created a button on the page that asks the user if they want to start over when the user clicks this button it does indeed reload everything except my .click functions, for loops, if statements in jquery.

How can I make my button reload the functions,loops,if statements?

I tried using remove(). It didn't work either. As you can see in my code when the user clicks on the button that says Yes! then the divs they have created are detached() from the code a long with most of the other elements on the page. After that I am using before() & after() to recreate the removed questions, spaces under them & their submit buttons. The problem is that the submit buttons no longer function after they are created again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Razzakun's Etch A Sketch</title>
</head>

<body>

<center><h1>Welcome to Razzakun's Etch A Sketch</h1><center>
<center><div id="verticalSquaresQuestion">How many vertical squares of Etch A Sketch Space do you want?</div></center>
<br>
<center><input id="vsquareInput" type="text" value="" /></center>
<br>
<center><input id="vsubmit" type="button" value="Submit" /></center>
<br>
<center><div id="horizontalSquaresQuestion">How many horizontal squares of Etch A Sketch Space do you want?</div></center>
<br>
<center><input id="hsquareInput" type="text" value="" /></center>
<br>
<center><input id="hsubmit" type="button" value="Submit" /></center>

</body>

</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


var creatingVDivs = 0;
var creatingHDivs = 0;
var createContainer = "<div id=container></div>";
var createHorizontalDivs="<div class= hsquare><center>Etch A Sketch</center></div>";
var createVerticalDivs = "<div class= vsquare><center>Etch A Sketch</center></div>";
var trueNumberOfVerticalSquares = 0;
var trueNumberOfHorizontalSquares = 0;
var $numOfVerticalSquares = $("#vsquareInput");
var $numOfHorizontalSquares = $("#hsquareInput");
var createEtchASketchLogoDiv = "<div id = logo><center><h3>Thank you for trying Razzakun's Etch A Sketch! </h3></center></div>";
var clearQuestion = "<div id= clearQuestion><center><h2>Do you want to start over?</h2></center></div>";
var clearQuestionSpace= "<br>";
var clearQuestionSubmit ="<center><input id='clearSubmit' type='button' value='Yes!' /></center>";
var verticalSquaresQuestion = "<center><div id='verticalSquaresQuestion'>How many vertical squares of Etch A Sketch Space do you want?</div></center>";
var vSquareInput = "<center><input id='vsquareInput' type='text' value='' /></center>";
var vSubmit = "<center><input id='vsubmit' type='button' value='Submit' /></center>";
var horizontalSquaresQuestion ="<br><br><center><div id='horizontalSquaresQuestion'>How many horizontal squares of Etch A Sketch Space do you want?</div></center>";
var hSquareInput = "<center><input id='hsquareInput' type='text' value='' /></center>";
var hSubmit= "<center><input id='hsubmit' type='button' value='Submit' /></center>";


$("#vsubmit").off("click").on("click", function () {

 trueNumberOfVerticalSquares = $numOfVerticalSquares.val();
 alert(trueNumberOfVerticalSquares + " vertical squares will be created. Click OK if that's okay.");

for(creatingVDivs=0; creatingVDivs < trueNumberOfVerticalSquares; creatingVDivs++) {

            $("body").append(createVerticalDivs); 
            $(".vsquare").height("200px");
            $(".vsquare").width("200px");
            $(".vsquare").css("margin", "0px");
            $(".vsquare").css("background-color","#eef7ff");





}

if(creatingVDivs >= trueNumberOfVerticalSquares){

   $("body").append(createContainer); 
   $("#logo").detach();
   $("#container").prepend( $( ".vsquare")); 
   $("#vsubmit").detach();
   $("#vsquareInput").detach();
   $("#verticalSquaresQuestion").detach();
   $("#clearQuestion").detach();
   $("<br>").detach();
   $("#clearSubmit").detach();
   $("#container").before(createEtchASketchLogoDiv);
   $("#logo").before(clearQuestion);
   $("#logo").before(clearQuestionSpace);
   $("#clearQuestion").after(clearQuestionSubmit);  


   $("#clearSubmit").off("click").on("click", function () {


    alert("Are you sure you really want to erase your hard work? Click OK if you are.");

$(".vsquare, .hsquare").detach();
$("#clearSubmit").detach();
$("#clearQuestion").detach();
$("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").detach();
$("#hsquareInput").detach();
$("#hsubmit").detach();
$("h1").after(verticalSquaresQuestion);
$("#verticalSquaresQuestion").after(vSquareInput);
$("#vsquareInput").after(vSubmit);
$("#verticalSquaresQuestion").after($("<br>"));
$("#vsubmit").before($("<br>"));
$("#vsubmit").after(horizontalSquaresQuestion);
$("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").after(hSquareInput);
$("#hsquareInput").after(hSubmit);
$("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").after($("<br>"));
$("#hsubmit").before($("<br>"));



});

}

});

$("#hsubmit").off("click").on("click", function () {

 trueNumberOfHorizontalSquares = $numOfHorizontalSquares.val();

 alert(trueNumberOfHorizontalSquares + " horizontal squares will be created. Click OK if that's okay.");


for(creatingHDivs=0; creatingHDivs < trueNumberOfHorizontalSquares; creatingHDivs++) {



                $("body").append(createHorizontalDivs); 
                $(".hsquare").height("200px");
                $(".hsquare").width("200px");
                $(".hsquare").css("margin", "0px");
                $(".hsquare").css("background-color","#eef7ff");
                $(".hsquare").css("padding","0px");
                $(".hsquare").css("float","left");
                $(".hsquare").css("display","block");

    }

if(creatingHDivs >= trueNumberOfHorizontalSquares){

   $("body").append(createContainer); 
   $("#logo").detach();
   $("#container").prepend( $( ".hsquare")); 
   $("#hsubmit").detach();
   $("#hsquareInput").detach();
   $("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").detach();
   $("#clearQuestion").detach();
   $("<br>").detach();
   $("#clearSubmit").detach();
   $("#container").before(createEtchASketchLogoDiv);
   $("#logo").before(clearQuestion);
   $("#logo").before(clearQuestionSpace);
   $("#clearQuestion").after(clearQuestionSubmit);


   $("#clearSubmit").off("click").on("click", function () {


    alert("Are you sure you really want to erase your hard work? Click OK if you are.");

$(".vsquare, .hsquare").detach();
$("#clearSubmit").detach();
$("#clearQuestion").detach();
$("#verticalSquaresQuestion").detach();
$("#vsquareInput").detach();
$("#vsubmit").detach();
$("h1").after(verticalSquaresQuestion);
$("#verticalSquaresQuestion").after(vSquareInput);
$("#vsquareInput").after(vSubmit);
$("#verticalSquaresQuestion").after($("<br>"));
$("#vsubmit").before($("<br>"));
$("#vsubmit").after(horizontalSquaresQuestion);
$("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").after(hSquareInput);
$("#hsquareInput").after(hSubmit);
$("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").after($("<br>"));
$("#hsubmit").before($("<br>"));




});

}


});


});

</script>
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how it was supposed to be formatted. I'm already receiving downvotes. Makes me really wary of using this site for help :/

Comment: @Razzakun I think the downvote was for not explaining clearly. Give examples, show the desired behavior, say what you tried - what didn't work, etc

Comment: @ViruZX Thank you for explaining that. I updated my post with a different explanation. Hopefully it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to renew the event handler, then try calling them again once you have recreated the DOM elements:

```
$("#vsubmit").before($("<br>"));
$("#vsubmit").after(horizontalSquaresQuestion);
$("#vsubmit").off("click").on("click", function () { ... });
```

Since `function () { ... }` is now being used multiple times and recursively, you must assign it to a variable.

```
var vsubmitListener = function () {
    trueNumberOfVerticalSquares = $numOfVerticalSquares.val();
    alert(trueNumberOfVerticalSquares + " vertical squares will be created. Click OK if that's okay.");

    for (creatingVDivs = 0; creatingVDivs < trueNumberOfVerticalSquares; creatingVDivs++) {
        $("body").append(createVerticalDivs);
        $(".vsquare").height("200px");
        $(".vsquare").width("200px");
        $(".vsquare").css("margin", "0px");
        $(".vsquare").css("background-color", "#eef7ff");
    }

    if (creatingVDivs >= trueNumberOfVerticalSquares) {
        $("body").append(createContainer);
        $("#logo").detach();
        $("#container").prepend($(".vsquare"));
        $("#vsubmit").detach();
        $("#vsquareInput").detach();
        $("#verticalSquaresQuestion").detach();
        $("#clearQuestion").detach();
        $("<br>").detach();
        $("#clearSubmit").detach();
        $("#container").before(createEtchASketchLogoDiv);
        $("#logo").before(clearQuestion);
        $("#logo").before(clearQuestionSpace);
        $("#clearQuestion").after(clearQuestionSubmit);

        $("#clearSubmit").off("click").on("click", function () {
            alert("Are you sure you really want to erase your hard work? Click OK if you are.");

            $(".vsquare, .hsquare").detach();
            $("#clearSubmit").detach();
            $("#clearQuestion").detach();
            $("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").detach();
            $("#hsquareInput").detach();
            $("#hsubmit").detach();
            $("h1").after(verticalSquaresQuestion);
            $("#verticalSquaresQuestion").after(vSquareInput);
            $("#vsquareInput").after(vSubmit);
            $("#verticalSquaresQuestion").after($("<br>"));
            $("#vsubmit").before($("<br>"));
            $("#vsubmit").after(horizontalSquaresQuestion);
            /* Now that is has a name, we can recursively call it */
            $("#vsubmit").off("click").on("click", vsubmitListener);
            /* We couldn't do that when it was an anonymous function literal  */
            $("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").after(hSquareInput);
            $("#hsquareInput").after(hSubmit);
            $("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").after($("<br>"));
            $("#hsubmit").before($("<br>"));
        });
    }
};
$("#vsubmit").off("click").on("click", vsubmitListener);
```

You'll have to do this for `#hsubmit` as well.

The following snippet works for me:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Razzakun's Etch A Sketch</title>
</head>

<body>

  <center>
    <h1>Welcome to Razzakun's Etch A Sketch</h1>
    <center>
      <center>
        <div id="verticalSquaresQuestion">How many vertical squares of Etch A Sketch Space do you want?</div>
      </center>
      <br>
      <center>
        <input id="vsquareInput" type="text" value="" />
      </center>
      <br>
      <center>
        <input id="vsubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
      </center>
      <br>
      <center>
        <div id="horizontalSquaresQuestion">How many horizontal squares of Etch A Sketch Space do you want?</div>
      </center>
      <br>
      <center>
        <input id="hsquareInput" type="text" value="" />
      </center>
      <br>
      <center>
        <input id="hsubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
      </center>

</body>

</html>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {


    var creatingVDivs = 0;
    var creatingHDivs = 0;
    var createContainer = "<div id=container></div>";
    var createHorizontalDivs = "<div class= hsquare><center>Etch A Sketch</center></div>";
    var createVerticalDivs = "<div class= vsquare><center>Etch A Sketch</center></div>";
    var trueNumberOfVerticalSquares = 0;
    var trueNumberOfHorizontalSquares = 0;
    var $numOfVerticalSquares = $("#vsquareInput");
    var $numOfHorizontalSquares = $("#hsquareInput");
    var createEtchASketchLogoDiv = "<div id = logo><center><h3>Thank you for trying Razzakun's Etch A Sketch! </h3></center></div>";
    var clearQuestion = "<div id= clearQuestion><center><h2>Do you want to start over?</h2></center></div>";
    var clearQuestionSpace = "<br>";
    var clearQuestionSubmit = "<center><input id='clearSubmit' type='button' value='Yes!' /></center>";
    var verticalSquaresQuestion = "<center><div id='verticalSquaresQuestion'>How many vertical squares of Etch A Sketch Space do you want?</div></center>";
    var vSquareInput = "<center><input id='vsquareInput' type='text' value='' /></center>";
    var vSubmit = "<center><input id='vsubmit' type='button' value='Submit' /></center>";
    var horizontalSquaresQuestion = "<br><br><center><div id='horizontalSquaresQuestion'>How many horizontal squares of Etch A Sketch Space do you want?</div></center>";
    var hSquareInput = "<center><input id='hsquareInput' type='text' value='' /></center>";
    var hSubmit = "<center><input id='hsubmit' type='button' value='Submit' /></center>";


    var vsubmitListener = function() {

      trueNumberOfVerticalSquares = $numOfVerticalSquares.val();
      alert(trueNumberOfVerticalSquares + " vertical squares will be created. Click OK if that's okay.");

      for (creatingVDivs = 0; creatingVDivs < trueNumberOfVerticalSquares; creatingVDivs++) {

        $("body").append(createVerticalDivs);
        $(".vsquare").height("200px");
        $(".vsquare").width("200px");
        $(".vsquare").css("margin", "0px");
        $(".vsquare").css("background-color", "#eef7ff");





      }

      if (creatingVDivs >= trueNumberOfVerticalSquares) {

        $("body").append(createContainer);
        $("#logo").detach();
        $("#container").prepend($(".vsquare"));
        $("#vsubmit").detach();
        $("#vsquareInput").detach();
        $("#verticalSquaresQuestion").detach();
        $("#clearQuestion").detach();
        $("<br>").detach();
        $("#clearSubmit").detach();
        $("#container").before(createEtchASketchLogoDiv);
        $("#logo").before(clearQuestion);
        $("#logo").before(clearQuestionSpace);
        $("#clearQuestion").after(clearQuestionSubmit);


        $("#clearSubmit").off("click").on("click", function() {


          alert("Are you sure you really want to erase your hard work? Click OK if you are.");

          $(".vsquare, .hsquare").detach();
          $("#clearSubmit").detach();
          $("#clearQuestion").detach();
          $("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").detach();
          $("#hsquareInput").detach();
          $("#hsubmit").detach();
          $("h1").after(verticalSquaresQuestion);
          $("#verticalSquaresQuestion").after(vSquareInput);
          $("#vsquareInput").after(vSubmit);
          $("#verticalSquaresQuestion").after($("<br>"));
          $("#vsubmit").before($("<br>"));
          $("#vsubmit").after(horizontalSquaresQuestion);
          $("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").after(hSquareInput);
          $("#hsquareInput").after(hSubmit);
          $("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").after($("<br>"));
          $("#hsubmit").before($("<br>"));

          $("#vsubmit").off("click").on("click", vsubmitListener);
          $("#hsubmit").off("click").on("click", hsubmitListener);


        });

      }

    };


    var hsubmitListener = function() {

      trueNumberOfHorizontalSquares = $numOfHorizontalSquares.val();

      alert(trueNumberOfHorizontalSquares + " horizontal squares will be created. Click OK if that's okay.");


      for (creatingHDivs = 0; creatingHDivs < trueNumberOfHorizontalSquares; creatingHDivs++) {



        $("body").append(createHorizontalDivs);
        $(".hsquare").height("200px");
        $(".hsquare").width("200px");
        $(".hsquare").css("margin", "0px");
        $(".hsquare").css("background-color", "#eef7ff");
        $(".hsquare").css("padding", "0px");
        $(".hsquare").css("float", "left");
        $(".hsquare").css("display", "block");

      }

      if (creatingHDivs >= trueNumberOfHorizontalSquares) {

        $("body").append(createContainer);
        $("#logo").detach();
        $("#container").prepend($(".hsquare"));
        $("#hsubmit").detach();
        $("#hsquareInput").detach();
        $("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").detach();
        $("#clearQuestion").detach();
        $("<br>").detach();
        $("#clearSubmit").detach();
        $("#container").before(createEtchASketchLogoDiv);
        $("#logo").before(clearQuestion);
        $("#logo").before(clearQuestionSpace);
        $("#clearQuestion").after(clearQuestionSubmit);


        $("#clearSubmit").off("click").on("click", function() {


          alert("Are you sure you really want to erase your hard work? Click OK if you are.");

          $(".vsquare, .hsquare").detach();
          $("#clearSubmit").detach();
          $("#clearQuestion").detach();
          $("#verticalSquaresQuestion").detach();
          $("#vsquareInput").detach();
          $("#vsubmit").detach();
          $("h1").after(verticalSquaresQuestion);
          $("#verticalSquaresQuestion").after(vSquareInput);
          $("#vsquareInput").after(vSubmit);
          $("#verticalSquaresQuestion").after($("<br>"));
          $("#vsubmit").before($("<br>"));
          $("#vsubmit").after(horizontalSquaresQuestion);
          $("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").after(hSquareInput);
          $("#hsquareInput").after(hSubmit);
          $("#horizontalSquaresQuestion").after($("<br>"));
          $("#hsubmit").before($("<br>"));


          $("#vsubmit").off("click").on("click", vsubmitListener);
          $("#hsubmit").off("click").on("click", hsubmitListener);


        });

      }


    };


    $("#vsubmit").off("click").on("click", vsubmitListener);
    $("#hsubmit").off("click").on("click", hsubmitListener);


  });
</script>
```

My recommendation though is to not delete any elements that you don't want to go away in the first place.

**EDIT:**

I have not used jQuery in a while, because I prefer to use native JavaScript.  In native JavaScript, is it required that you reattach event listeners whenever an element is removed and reinserted into the DOM.

The jQuery `.on()` handler is supposed to result in persistent event handling, adding the event listener to any element inserted into the DOM which matches the selector.  I think this problem could also be solved by figured how why your code is somehow having jQuery remove the `.on()` event listeners.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply!  I am learning a lot from it :)